# How to change the text in standard dialog button in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7

How can I change the "OK" text into "Great!" on all buttons in Windows 7's dialog windows?

Comment: I really doubt they'd let you do that.

Comment: @asveikau If by "they" you mean the operating system, then I am confident that it is possible. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Possible or not, why would you want to do such a thing?  Hijinx?

Comment: @Wonko the Sane: No, just for my own pleasure :)

Comment: Oh, I know it's possible to change the localized resources that the Windows binaries in system32 use.  But why would they tell the general public how to do it?  That is a support nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

The `MessageBox` function is documented as being in User32.dll. Modify that and you should be set.

A couple of caveats:

- This is an important system DLL and Microsoft will have gone to some lengths to keep it from being modified. Not only will you have trouble modifying it, but if you succeed Windows might restore it from a backup as soon as it can.
- If you screw up you might make your system unbootable.
- If I ever find you doing this to any PC of mine, prepare to hide and hide well, because I will be looking for you.